# Как переделать bash скрипт с curl'om в php?

Tags: php, bash, curl

Был такой скрипт который сверял файлы на моём сайте и на другом, он смотрел вроде бы на дату скаченного файла и на дату с другого сайта, если файлы были одинаковые то скрипт ничего не качал, по заголовкам вроде определял. Если файлы были разными тогда качал.  Работал он на баше (sh скрипте) раньше, сейчас хочу перевести на php.

Вот собственно он:

```js
Скрипт скачивал file.json.gz другого сайта и распаковывал (или копировал) уже ко мне в папку с сайтом

#!/bin/bash
FNAME="file.json"
URL="http://site2.ru/fff.json"
GNAME="/home/user/bin/getdata/${FNAME}.gz"
curl --fail -R -z "${GNAME}" -o "${GNAME}" -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip" "${URL}" && \
 gunzip -c "${GNAME}" > /home/user/mysite.ru/files/"${FNAME}"
```

А вот чуток не доработанный мой скрипт на PHP

```js
<?php

class getJson{
  static public function get($localFile,$urls,$remoteFile)
{

$urls .=$remoteFile;

if (file_exists($localFile)) {
$timestamp = filemtime($localFile);
}


$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$urls); //conf
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1); //вывод строчкой
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true); // читать заголовок
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1); // читать ТОЛЬКО заголовок без тела
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 60); // таймаут соединения
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60); // таймаут ответа
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, TRUE); //без кеша
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILETIME, TRUE); //получить timestamp файла
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "gzip"); //установка кодировки

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEVALUE, $timestamp); //время изменения файла на моём сервере
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMECONDITION, CURL_TIMECOND_IFMODSINCE); 

  $content = curl_exec( $ch );
  $err     = curl_errno( $ch );
  $errmsg  = curl_error( $ch );
  $header  = curl_getinfo( $ch );
  curl_close( $ch );
  $header['errno']   = $err;
  $header['errmsg']  = $errmsg;
  $header['content'] = $content;
  return $header;
  //ответ на подобии такого
  //array(25) { ["url"]=> string(42) "http://serv1.ru/files/11.json" ["content_type"]=> string(9) "text/html" ["http_code"]=> int(200) ["header_size"]=> int(185) ["request_size"]=> int(147) ["filetime"]=> int(1523617841) ["ssl_verify_result"]=> int(0) ["redirect_count"]=> int(0) ["total_time"]=> float(0.188) ["namelookup_time"]=> float(0) ["connect_time"]=> float(0.094) ["pretransfer_time"]=> float(0.094) ["size_upload"]=> float(0) ["size_download"]=> float(0) ["speed_download"]=> float(0) ["speed_upload"]=> float(0) ["download_content_length"]=> float(-1) ["upload_content_length"]=> float(0) ["starttransfer_time"]=> float(0.188) ["redirect_time"]=> float(0) ["certinfo"]=> array(0) { } ["redirect_url"]=> string(0) "" ["errno"]=> int(0) ["errmsg"]=> string(0) "" ["content"]=> string(185) "HTTP/1.1 200 Forbidden Referrer-Policy: same-origin Last-Modified: Mon, 07 May 2018 11:33:05 GMT Content-type: text/html Date: Mon, 07 May 2018 03:46:11 GMT Server: TrashServer
  
}

}

?>
```

```js
$getJsonLinks = array(
  'http://serv1.ru/files',
  'http://serv2.com/loadings/',
  'http://serv3.jp/oth/'
);


getJsonPooling('localfile.json',$getJsonLinks,0,'remotefile.json');

function getJsonPooling($localFile,$arr,$num,$remoteFile){
$getJson = new getJson();
$gg = $getJson->get($localFile, $arr[$num] ,$remoteFile);
if ( ($gg['errno']) && ($num <= count($arr)-2 ) ) {
$num++;
echo $num;
getJsonPooling($localFile,$arr,$num,$remoteFile);
}
var_dump($gg);
}
```

UPD:

Вроде сделал на PHP, вроде работает

```js
<?php

function getJsonPooling($localFile,$arr,$num,$remoteFile){
$numReq = $num+1;
echo 'ПОПЫТКА ПОДКЛЮЧЕНИЯ: '.$numReq.'<br>';
echo 'Подключаемся к: '.$arr[$num].'<br>';
$getJson = new getJson();
$getPlaylist = $getJson->get($localFile, $arr[$num] ,$remoteFile);
if (  ($getPlaylist['returnurl']['errno']) || 
  ($getPlaylist['returnfile']['errno']) && 
  ($num <= count($arr)-2 )  ) {
    $num++;
    getJsonPooling($localFile,$arr,$num,$remoteFile);
  }
  var_dump($getPlaylist);
}

class getJson{
  static public function get($localFile,$url,$remoteFile)
{


$url .=$remoteFile;

if (file_exists($localFile)) {
$timestamp = filemtime($localFile);
}

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url); //conf

/*curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, '51.255.138.248:3128'); //PROXY's*/

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1); // возвратить то что вернул сервер
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true); // читать заголовок
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1); // читать ТОЛЬКО заголовок без тела
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 60); // таймаут соединения
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60); // таймаут ответа
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, TRUE); //без кеша
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILETIME, TRUE); //получить timestamp файла
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "gzip"); //установка кодировки
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEVALUE, $timestamp); //время локального файла для сверки

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMECONDITION, CURL_TIMECOND_IFMODSINCE); //Если файл не изменился получаем код 304

  curl_exec( $ch );
  $returnurl  = curl_getinfo( $ch );
  $returnurl['errno']   = curl_errno( $ch );
  $returnurl['errmsg']  = curl_error( $ch );
  
if( 
  ($returnurl['http_code'] == '200') &&
  ($returnurl['errno'] == '0')
){

echo '<br> Файл изменился, качаем!';
echo '<hr>';
$ch2 = curl_copy_handle($ch); //Копируем предыдущий дескриптор
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_HEADER, false); // читать заголовок
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_NOBODY, false); // читать ТОЛЬКО заголовок без тела
$outData = curl_exec( $ch2 );
$isJSON = (is_string($outData) &&
(is_object(json_decode($outData)) ||
is_array(json_decode($outData)))) ? true : false;

  $returnfile  = curl_getinfo( $ch2 );
  $returnfile['errno']   = curl_errno( $ch2 );
  $returnfile['errmsg']  = curl_error( $ch2 );
  $returnfile['valid'] = $isJSON;

curl_close($ch2);

if ($returnfile['http_code'] != '200') {
  echo 'Ошибка на сервере при получении файла: '.$returnfile['http_code'];
}

if ($returnfile['errno'] != '0'){
echo '<br> Ошибка при получении файла: '.$returnfile['errno'].'<br>';
echo '<br>'.$returnfile['errmsg'].'<br>';
}

if($isJSON) {
echo '<br>Полученный файл корректный, записываем! <br>';
file_put_contents($localFile, $outData);
$GLOBALS['data'] = $outData;
unset($outData);
} else {
echo '<br>Полученный файл НЕ корректный <br>';
die();
}

} else if ($returnurl['http_code'] == '304'){
echo '<br> Файл не изменился <br>';
} else if ($returnurl['errno'] != '0'){
echo '<br> Ошибка: '.$returnurl['errno'].'<br>';
echo '<br>'.$returnurl['errmsg'].'<br>';
}

curl_close($ch);

$return['returnurl'] = $returnurl;
$return['returnfile'] = $returnfile;

  return $return;
  }
}
?>
```

Запускаю так:

```js
$localFile = './files/local.json';
$remoteFile = 'remotefile.json';

//Зеркала
$getJsonLinks = array(
  'http://serv1.ru/',
  'http://serv2.com/',
  'http://serv3.org/'
);

//локальный файл, массив с ссылками на сайт, номер ссылки из масива (если не работает ссылка идём к следующей ссылке), файл который качаем по ссылке
getJsonPooling($localFile,$getJsonLinks,0,$remoteFile);
```

Что тут можно подправить для оптимизации/лаконичности ?

Answer (score 1):

Лучше определяйте по md5 hash, если он разный то файл 100% изменялся на сервере.

Вот набросал пример, под себя думаю подгоните.

```
    // Локальный файл
    $filename_local = file_get_contents('http://site.com/test.txt');
    $md5file_local = md5_file($filename_local);

    // Файл на сервере
    $filename_dev = file_get_contents('http://site.com/dev/test.txt');
    $md5file_dev = md5_file($filename_dev);

    // Сверяем md5 hash и если он отличается, значит файл изменен, закачиваем его
    if ($md5file_local != $md5file_dev) {
        file_put_contents('test.txt', $md5file_dev);
    }
```

Comment: $filename_dev = file_get_contents('http://site.com/dev/test.txt'); мне кажется он так его в любом случае скачает. надо желательно по курлу, что бы трафик лишний не тратить и скачивать только тогда когда файл поменялся. Надо скачивать в gz архиве хоть и файл в формате json, там есть поддержка gzip. если мой файл curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEVALUE, $timestamp); совпадает с файлом на другом сервере получаем ответ 304 и файл не должен качаться. в общем надо как в баш скрипте только на пыхе )

Comment: Он не будет качать файл если md5 хеши одинаковые)

Comment: Ну так что бы прочитать md5 хеш ему нужен файл, соответственно он его скачает. Запрос на сервер за файлом будет, а тут мы читаем только заголовки без файла. Если дата файла меньше чем дата файла с удалённого сервера то тогда качаем, иначе получаем ответ код 304. Думаю если сделать $filename_dev = file_get_contents('http://site.com/dev/test.txt'); и посмотреть по логам на удалённом сервере, то они покажут что файл скачивали. не так ли ?

Comment: Можно не использовать file_get_contents, md5_file может удаленно проверять файл